# Chrome not detecting extension's content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest, google-chrome-devtools

I recently created a redirect extension and loaded it, unpacked, onto Google Chrome. After not working, I went to debug it. However, my content script is not showing up under the "Content scripts" tab of the Chrome developer tools. Is it not supposed to show up there? Or is my code wrong?

Code:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "myCache",
  "description": "This extension redirects from iBoss' page blocked website to the earlier targeted website.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://cb.iphantom.com/*"],
      "js": ["redirect.js"]
    }
  ],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  }
}
```

Comment: Your manifest.json is valid, redirect.js should be visible in sources tab but only for matching website, that is cb.iphantom.com, it will not be visible for any other page because it is executed for matching page only. Is it invisible on the page iphantom? Are you opening devtools on page cb.iphantom.com?

Comment: Ahhhhh. That makes so much more sense. No, I was not opening the devtools on the website. I just did and it's showing up. Thanks for the help!